# Modifying run configurations from gradle CLI

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

I am writing an Android Application (app) which has dependency on a library (lib). I want to run the unit test cases present in this library.

Running the test cases as it is, gave me this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
```

Changing the ***working directory path*** in the **run/debug configurations** from 'lib' to 'app' helped me resolve this issue.

However, when I run the same test cases using Gradle CLI, the test cases fail with the same error as above.

Can someone tell me how/where to set the working directory while using gradle/gradlew please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working directory is your working directory is your working directory.

Just cd into app before you call gradle / gradlew and your working directory is app.

You can of course also set the `workingDir` property of the task of type `Test` that runs to make it independent of the dir where you are executing Gradle which probably is the better variant.

Comment: My gradlew and gradlew.bat files are at the project level and not module level. Hence, if I cd into app before calling gradlew, I get this error. 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: And regarding your second approach, could you please give me an example or a code snippet perhaps?

Comment: I played around a little bit and now I understand what you meant. I added a task and set the working dir property within it. Thanks a lot for the quick help!

`tasks.withType(Test) {
    workingDir = ('some_path')
}`

Comment: Of course `gradlew` will not be found in the first case. You need to call `../gradlew` or `..\gradlew.bat` then.